# EmberJS: how to know if route was called because the user clicked the Back button

Tags: ember.js, routes, browser-history

I need to know whether my route was called because the user clicked the browser Back button instead of clicking a {{link-to}} link to get there.  The reason for this is because of I have a filterable list with pagination on the associated template for that route.  If the user navigates away from this list and then clicks the back button, my designer wants the state of the filters to be in tact.  However, if the users clicks a link to arrive at this list, my designer wants the filter and pagination to be reset.

Example:

```
1) Users clicks the 'Books' navigation link and arrives at '/books'.
2) User filters the list goes to page 2 of results.  This does not update the URL and user is still at '/books'.
3) User clicks one of the Books and goes to '/books/123'.
4) User clicks the browser Back button and goes back to '/books'.  I need to show the filtered list at page 2.
5) User clicks the 'About Us' link and goes to '/about'
6) User clicks the 'Books' navigation link and arrives at '/books'.  But this time, the user didn't click the browser Back button to arrive here, so I need to reset the filters and show a list of unfiltered Books on page 1.
```

In both step 4 and step 6, the user arrives at '/books' and BooksRoute, but the mechanism they used to arrive there differs, so I need to show a different books list result.  Is there a way to tell if a Route was called because the Back button was clicked instead of clicking a hyperlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without saving state in the url, I'd probably create a dummy route that eliminates `books` state when accessed through that link.  (I assume the controller is where you're keeping track of this state).

#### Router

```
this.resource('books', function(){
  this.route('all');    
});
```

#### Route

```
App.BooksAllRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(){
    var booksController = this.controllerFor('books');
    booksController.set('filters', {});
    // replaceWith replaces the history instead of adding additional history
    // this may not be necessary since we're doing it mid transition
    // this.transitionTo may be more appropriate
    this.replaceWith('books');
  }
});
```

#### Template

```
{{link-to 'Books' 'books.all'}}
```

You might need to move the dummy route to the same level in the router so as to avoid having the books model already being populated.  (I'm guessing about how you're actually filtering your results)

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you.  But it created another one.  I have a books.loading route that displays a spinner.  It goes into this intermediate state until the model hook's promise is fulfilled.  Before BooksAllRoute.setupController() is called, I see the books.loading template being rendered.  However, once I call this.replaceWith('books'), the books.loading template no longer shows even though the browser console shows that it did properly transition into the intermediate 'books.loading' state.  Any way to restore 'books.loading' after calling this.replaceWith('books')?

Comment: I'll have to try and reproduce that, I don't think I've seen it before.

Comment: So I know this is probably different than your current setup, but would you mind making the finishing touches on the jsbin, It'll be easier to chase down if I actually start from a known point, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/682/edit

Comment: I created a jsbin to try to replicate my problem but everything works, so there's nothing wrong with what you proposed.  There must be something else wrong with my app.

Comment: I did notice a strange behavior with this solution.  Here's a jsbin to demonstrate: http://jsbin.com/harusuxo/3.  Try clicking 'Books', then 'Book 1', then try going Back twice.  You can't get back to the original screen.  It looks like Route.replaceWith() is replacing the previous history state before the 'books/all' history state is added to the history stack.

Comment: Hah, yeah, I thought that might happen, I wasn't sure what would happen mid transition using replaceWith, it apparently doesn't complete the transition, and replaces the previous history (I postulated that above in the comments).  That just means you can use `transitionTo` mid transition and the current transition is replaced with the new transition. http://jsbin.com/harusuxo/6/edit